# Check dovecot (md5crypt) login with php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dovecot

How can check if a given user/pass is correct with the stored login information from Dovecot in a MySQL DB? Passwords are currently stored in md5crypt.

I want to do this with PHP and MySQL query if possible, not with `/usr/bin/doveadm auth`

Comment: Use the `crypt` function for this.

Comment: Ideally you would use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure).